# HTML entities showing up as ? only when served through Jetty

Tags: jetty, html-entities, enlive

My HTML entities, such as `&copy;` and `mdash;` are showing up as ?, both when rendered on the page and when I view the underlying source -- but only when served through my production Jetty server (in the `webapps` directory).

The HTML entities look fine in when served from static files through a local Nginx. They also look good when run through a development run of a Pedestal app using embedded Jetty. Here is the HTML head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
  <meta content="Web Site Description" name="description" />
  <meta content="The Author" name="author" />
  <link href="/images/favicon-128x128.png" type="image/png" rel="shortcut icon" />
  <title>A Really Great Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/shared.css" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
    </script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

How do I solve this? What might be going wrong? Or, failing that, how do I debug?

Some ideas:

First, I'm using Jetty 9.1.X in production. My development server uses (from `lein deps :tree`):

```
[io.pedestal/pedestal.jetty "0.2.2"]
   [javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api "3.0.1"]
   [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server "8.1.9.v20130131"]
     [org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.servlet "3.0.0.v201112011016"]
     [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-continuation "8.1.9.v20130131"]
     [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http "8.1.9.v20130131"]
       [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io "8.1.9.v20130131"]
         [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util "8.1.9.v20130131"]
   [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlet "8.1.9.v20130131"]
     [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-security "8.1.9.v20130131"]
```

Are there Jetty 9 production settings I should double check?

Second, I'm using [Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive). It relies on the following dependencies (from `lein deps :tree`):

```
[enlive "1.1.5"]
   [org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup/tagsoup "1.2.1"]
   [org.jsoup/jsoup "1.7.2"]
```

I wonder if somehow [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) is behaving differently in production versus development.

**Update**:

Here are the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: ring-session=eyTI ... <SNIP> ... s%3D;Path=/
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.1.3.v20140225)
```

The `text/html;charset=UTF-8` seems to rule out that Jetty is the problem. I think it is possible (even likely) that TagSoup is not behaving as I would expect.

I am currently reading this thread on the Enlive mailing list: [mdash output as question mark](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/enlive-clj/html%2420entities/enlive-clj/sa8Kvp_Nk9Q/SzdzeBnMvR0J).

**Update**: My Clojure templating (I was using Enlive but I just switched to [Laser](https://github.com/raynes/laser) -- but both behave the same in this regard) converts the HTML entities to Unicode. The problem seems to be that my installation Jetty 9 is not configured (or I'm not giving it what it needs) to handle the Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying UTF-8 encoding when starting Jetty solved the problem.

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar start.jar
```

Also, here is the Chef cookbook I use in case it helps you: https://github.com/bluemont/chef-jetty